# Getting ranged data value from varchar(500)

Tags: sql-server, substring, varchar, charindex, ssms-2014

Looking for some ideas.

I'm running SQL Server 2014. I have a `varchar(500)` column that has a data value that I need to extract from each row, however, it is not always in the same position on the row (sometimes off by 1 or 2 positions) so I'm having difficulty with the substring:

```
substring(Failure_Reason, charindex('Pressure received:', Failure_Reason + 181, 5) as 'Test'
```

Using this line of code, most of the time I get the correct data value, however sometimes I get a value like '67.T'

The `varchar` column's content is:

```
Settings received from Creep tester are outside expected values for pouch 3.            Pressure Duration received : 0. This value should be 32 +/- 2.          Pressure received : 198.5. This value should be between 202.77 and 197.24..
```

The verbage is always the same but the data values would be different

I'm just trying to parse out the value after the "Pressure Received:" but as it may be a position or two off in certain rows, I sometimes pull in the "." or the "T", is there a way to catch the value between the "Pressure Received:" and the "This", so I only get the numeric value?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, by off by a column or two i was referring to if you would put that line of text in notepad and select a certain number/letter, it shows you the the column of it on bottom right , so for example, im searching for column 181  in each row based off my code, perhaps column isnt the right word here :) maybe spaces is a better word

Answer (score 0):

The following should show you how to approach this:

1. Start position is location of string "Pressure received :" + the length of that string + 1
2. End position is the location of the string "This" - 1, with the search for this string starting at the position calculated in step 1
3. Get the substring between the two values calculated in the previous step
4. Trim the substring
5. If the last char in the substring is ".", substring it again to a length of 1 less than the current length

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the tips, i assume this is just a nested substring? im a newbie when it comes to a bit more advanced querying unfortunately  .would this approach still work even though the position of the words may not always be the same? the data value can be the one decimal place. therefore the end of the string would be either the "  " after the data value or before the "This"? would you be able to show me an example of this to better help me understand? thanks!

Comment: the issue im getting is when i try to use the end position of the string "This", its not pulling the correct one as there are multiple "This" in the row. would there be a way to limit this substring CharIndex to only look in a specific position of the string?(181 as shown in my question)

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. These types of function are often implemented in a specific way by each DBMS, so without knowing which one you are using it is impossible to give a solution we know will work for you. However, in general, CHARINDEX takes 3 parameters with the 3rd one being optional and being the position to start the search. It is this start position that is calculated in step 1 in my answer and is plugged in to step 2

Comment: hi nick, im using SQL server management studio, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
 --==== Setup some test data
Declare @testData Table (Failure_Reason varchar(500));
 Insert Into @testData (Failure_Reason)
 Values ('Settings received from Creep tester are outside expected values for pouch 3.            Pressure Duration received : 0. This value should be 32 +/- 2.          Pressure received : 198.5. This value should be between 202.77 and 197.24..')
      , ('Settings received from Creep tester are outside expected values for pouch 3.            Pressure Duration received : 0. This value should be 32 +/- 2.          Pressure received : 98.5. This value should be between 202.77 and 197.24..')
      , ('Settings received from Creep tester are outside expected values for pouch 3.            Pressure Duration received : 0. This value should be 32 +/- 2.          Pressure received : 8.5. This value should be between 202.77 and 197.24..');

 --==== Solution
 Select *
      , PressureReceived = substring(td.Failure_Reason, p1.pos, p2.pos - p1.pos - 1)
   From @testData                                                                         As td
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('Pressure received :', td.Failure_Reason, 1) + 20))      As p1(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('. This', td.Failure_Reason, p1.pos) + 1))               As p2(pos);
```

Comment: hi Jeff! thanks for taking the time to review my question, i tried taking your code and trying it out on my data, but im getting the error 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.' i assume this is because the "This" is at different positions? i edited your sample code by putting a few blank spaces before the "This" or taking away a blank space, and i got the same error message. any ideas?

Comment: If the string does not contain the values - you will get that error.  You must have rows that do not conform to the same structure, that is - they don't have either 'Pressure received :' or '. This'.

Comment: You can comment out the column using the substring - and review the pos columns.  For those where either p1.pos or p2.pos is equal to 0 are the rows where you have a problem with the input string.  You could also add a WHERE p1.pos = 0 Or p2.pos = 0 to isolate down to just those rows.